# Plotting the content of numpy arrays in matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the content of the arrays `x` and `lj` in the following code. However, the point in the plots are not the one inside the arrays. Can someone help me see the mistake I did ? I am still new in python.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import math 

lj=np.arange(10, dtype=np.float).reshape(10,1)
x=np.arange(10, dtype=np.float).reshape(10,1)

lj.fill(0)
x.fill(0)

for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i,0]=i*0.1
    lj[i,0]=4.0*( (1.0/(x[i,0]+0.0000001) )**12 - ( 1.0/(x[i,0]+0.0000001) )**6 )
    

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i,0],"\t\t\t",lj[i,0])

plt.plot(x,lj,"o")
plt.show()
```

This is the content of the arrayys and the follwoiing one is the plot done with `plt.plot()`

```
0.0                      4e+84
0.1                      3999948000335.996
0.2                      976494140.831542
0.30000000000000004      7521188.628402116
0.4                      237441.3028118298
0.5                      16127.960985650918
0.6000000000000001       1751.8371605495026
0.7000000000000001       254.9905579573781
0.8                      42.94879598363375
0.9                      6.636105087302215
```

[image]

Comment: This is the value at ```x=0``` . the problem is with the other values after ```0``` in the x-axis

Comment: `0` is the singularity, remove it from your data, you would see a better curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost division by zero
The plot is correct, lj[0] is almost equal to infinity, remove the first element, to get a better curve